# C coding: Can't seem to understand why code doesn't wait for standard input, but if I run independently it works fine

Tags: c

I will try to explain the issue here. 
I have written this code that accepts various types of inputs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>

int main()
{   
int number;
printf("press <ENTER> to continue...");
while( getchar() != '\n' );

char *p, s[100];
int n=0;


printf("enter a number: ");
while (fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin))
{
    n = strtol(s, &p, 10);
   if (p == s || *p != '\n')
        {
        printf("Invalid integer, please try again: ");
        }
    else
        break;
}

printf("You entered: %d\n", n);
printf("Enter an integer between 10 and 20: ");
scanf("%d", &number);
while (1)
{
    if (number < 10 || number > 20)
    {
    printf("Invalid value, 10 < value < 20: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
printf("You entered: %d\n", number);

//part 3 
double decpart;
printf("Enter a floating number num: ");
char buf[100];
int len;
char *endptr;

while (1)
{
    fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin);
    len = strlen(buf)-1;

    // right strip spaces (replace by linefeed like fgets ends the input)
    while(len>0)
    {
        len--;
        if (buf[len]==' ')
        {
            buf[len]='\n';
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    double floatnum = strtod(buf,&endptr);

    if (endptr[0]!='\n')
    {
        printf("Invalid floating point number, enter again: ");
    }
    else
    {
        int intpart = (int)floatnum;
        double decpart = floatnum - intpart;
        if (decpart == 0.000000){
            printf("Invalid floating point number, enter again: ");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Number entered = %.2f\n", floatnum);
            break;
        }
    }
}

double floatnum1;
printf("Enter a floating point number between 10.00 and 20.00: ");
scanf("%lf", &floatnum1);
while (1)
{
    if (floatnum1 < 10.00 || floatnum1 > 20.00)
    {
        printf("Invalid value, 10.000000 < value < 20.000000: ");
        scanf("%lf", &floatnum1);
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
printf("You entered: %0.2lf\n", floatnum1);
printf("End of tester program for milestone one!\n");

return 0;
```

}

Problem occurs on Part 3 of this code.  I see on screen  **Enter a floating number num:**  and immediately without waiting for user input it prints  **Invalid floating point number, enter again:**

This is not the case if I just run part3(commented here in code as //part3) independently, it just works fine.

Any idea, why that is happening?

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this behaviour lies in the usage of [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) followed by [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets)

`scanf` reads a number from standard input, and stops as soon as it encounters a non-digit character, which is the newline in this case.

Next `fgets` reads a whole line. But now there's still the single newline in the input, which satisfies `fgets` even though this is only an *empty* line.

When you skip over whitespace and finally check for a newline, `endptr` only points to a `\0` character. Thus the message

> Invalid floating point number, enter again:

---

To fix this, you must first skip whitespace before reading further with `fgets`.

Comment: Perfect, Thanks :) I was not aware of this concept before. Good to know @olaf